# table in table-environment - text is badly formated

Tags: tables

i have a Table:

```
\begin{center}
   \begin{tabular}
   ....
   ....
   \end{tabular}
  \caption{}
 \end{center}
```

And it looks fine, and works fine, except the caption is sometimes not next to the table^^ and i cant auto-generate a list of tables
if i change to {table} like This:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\subsection{subsection}
\linespread{1.5} %regulate line spacing
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{11pt}{0}\selectfont} 
\citeauthor{batak2013impact} erforschen desshalb die Häufigkeit und Intensitität von chronischer Müdigkeit und den möglichen Zusammenhang zu Schichtdiensten. Die Studie wird am Emergency Center des Clinical Center von Vojvodina in Novi Sad, Serbien im Zeitraum von Dezember 2012 bis Februar 2013 durchgeführt. Als Sample werden 120 zufällig gewählte Pflegekräfte der Krankenanstalt ausgewählt. 50\% der Gruppe (60 Personen) befinden sich in der Gruppe der im Schichtdienst arbeitenden. Die restlichen 50\% haben übliche 8 Stunden Tagesarbeitszeiten. Jede Testperson muss zwei Fragebögen ausfüllen. Einen um demographische Iformationen (Alter, Geschlecht, Jahre im Dienst, soziales Leben, ...) zu erfragen. Der zweite besteht aus einem standardisiertem Fragebogen um den Teilnehmern einen Wert entsprechend dem Piper Fatigue Scale (PFS) zu geben. Je höher dieser Wert, umso höher die chronische Müdigkeit. Ausgewertet werden die Ergebnisse Computerunterstützt.

Aufgrund der dempgraphischen Daten kann man an der Studie erkennen, das tendenziell jüngere Pflegekräfte im Schichtdienst arbeiten und ältere Pflegekräfte zum 8 Stunden Tag tendieren. Drüber hinaus sind die Antworten im FPS-Fragebogen in allen 22 Fragen, von Schichtarbeitenden Pflegekräften, signifikant höher (schlechter) bewertet. So wurde die subjektiv wahrgenommene Müdigkeit der letzten 7 Tage bei nichtschichtarbeitenden im Durchschnitt zwischen 1 und 6 bewertet. Die Schichtarbeitenden Kollegen und Kolleginnen hingegen bewerteten dies mit 6-10. Ebenso stellt sich heraus, dass verheiratete und Eltern tedenziell eher 8 Stunden Regeldienste bevorzugen. 

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{ | p{4cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | }
        \hline
           & 8-9h & 10-11h & 12-13h & >13h \\
         \hline
          Prozent von ALLEN Teilnehmern: & 26\% & 4\% & 65\% &   5\%  \\
         \hline
          Zufrieden mit dem Dienstplan & 85\% & 82\% & 88\% & 84\% \\
          Flexiebe Dienstpläne sind möglich: & 67\% & 65\% & 73\% & 66\% \\
          Burnout Risiko: & 20\% & 31\% & 44\% & 56\% \\
          Unzufirieden mit dem Job:  & 24\% & 35\% & 25\% & 43\% \\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{\ref{table:3} Anteil in \% nach Schichtgruppe \autocite[eigene Darstellung, 2019 nach][S. 2505]{batak2013impact}}
    \label{table:3}
\end{table}
\citeauthor{batak2013impact} erforschen desshalb die Häufigkeit und Intensitität von chronischer Müdigkeit und den möglichen Zusammenhang zu Schichtdiensten. Die Studie wird am Emergency Center des Clinical Center von Vojvodina in Novi Sad, Serbien im Zeitraum von Dezember 2012 bis Februar 2013 durchgeführt. Als Sample werden 120 zufällig gewählte Pflegekräfte der Krankenanstalt ausgewählt. 50\% der Gruppe (60 Personen) befinden sich in der Gruppe der im Schichtdienst arbeitenden. Die restlichen 50\% haben übliche 8 Stunden Tagesarbeitszeiten. Jede Testperson muss zwei Fragebögen ausfüllen. Einen um demographische Iformationen (Alter, Geschlecht, Jahre im Dienst, soziales Leben, ...) zu erfragen. Der zweite besteht aus einem standardisiertem Fragebogen um den Teilnehmern einen Wert entsprechend dem Piper Fatigue Scale (PFS) zu geben. Je höher dieser Wert, umso höher die chronische Müdigkeit. Ausgewertet werden die Ergebnisse Computerunterstützt.

Aufgrund der dempgraphischen Daten kann man an der Studie erkennen, das tendenziell jüngere Pflegekräfte im Schichtdienst arbeiten und ältere Pflegekräfte zum 8 Stunden Tag tendieren. Drüber hinaus sind die Antworten im FPS-Fragebogen in allen 22 Fragen, von Schichtarbeitenden Pflegekräften, signifikant höher (schlechter) bewertet. So wurde die subjektiv wahrgenommene Müdigkeit der letzten 7 Tage bei nichtschichtarbeitenden im Durchschnitt zwischen 1 und 6 bewertet. Die Schichtarbeitenden Kollegen und Kolleginnen hingegen bewerteten dies mit 6-10. Ebenso stellt sich heraus, dass verheiratete und Eltern tedenziell eher 8 Stunden Regeldienste bevorzugen. 
\end{document}
```

i get some kind of a messy table:
[image: Table with {table}]

Comment: Firstly `\caption` already add "Tabelle ..." for you no need of `Tabelle \ref{...}`

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documenclass as well as the relevant packages that are needed to reproduce the output you show.

Comment: So which of the pictures is the "messy" table? No offense, but they both look kinda bad. (Or is it just with and without the `\newline`s?) I'd suggest at the very least replacing the fixed-width `p{2cm}` columns with something like `c`. And have a look at the [booktabs package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `booktabs` you can achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{  l  c  c  c  c  }
        \toprule
           & 8-9 h & 10-11 h & 12-13 h & \textgreater 13 h \\
         \midrule
          Prozent von ALLEN Teilnehmern: & 26\% & 4\% & 65\% &   5\%  \\
         \midrule
          Zufrieden mit dem Dienstplan:  & 85\% & 82\% & 88\% & 84\% \\
          Flexible Dienstpläne sind möglich:  & 67\% & 65\% & 73\% & 66\% \\
          Burnout Risiko:  & 20\% & 31\% & 44\% & 56\% \\
          Unzufrieden mit dem Job:  & 24\% & 35\% & 25\% & 43\% \\ 
         \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Anteil in \% nach Schichtgruppe }
    \label{table:3}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, with `booktabs` table looks nicer ... i intend to add this in addendum, however, you was faster :-) (+1)

Comment: yeah looks realy neat, but same problem, the:
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{11pt}{0}\selectfont} 
kills the design ...

Comment: @Maxi: What exactly is the purpose of the above mentioned command? The documentclass option already sets the font size to 11pt. Could you please explain why you use this command?

Answer (score 3):

in lack of important information about your document preamble, we can only guessing about it design ...

with the following *mwe* (minimal working example), in which i

- remove all `newline` commands
- increase `arraystratch` with \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
- remove `[0.5ex]`
- extend table to text width by use of `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`

i obtain the following result:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf, font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
   \begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb] % <---
\centering
    \newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                | l | *{4}{c<{\,\%}|} }
    \hline
    & \mcc{8-9h} & \mcc{10-11h} & \mcc{12-13h} & \mcc{$>13$h} \\
    \hline
Prozent von ALLEN Teilnehmern:      & 26 & 4  & 65 &  5  \\
    \hline
Zufrieden mit dem Dienstplan        & 85 & 82 & 88 & 84 \\
Flexiebe Dienstpläne sind möglich:  & 67 & 65 & 73 & 66 \\
Burnout Risiko:                     & 20 & 31 & 44 & 56 \\
Unzufirieden mit dem Job:           & 24 & 35 & 25 & 43 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular*}
\caption{Anteil in \% nach Schichtgruppe \cite[eigene Darstellung, 2019 nach, S. 2505]{batak2013impact}}
\label{table:3}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

however, regarding your question title, it is still unclear what is your problem (beside table looks).

Comment: \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

Comment: @Maxi, pleas add this to your question, here is not visible to others ... and please from this fragment and table code in question compose one, complete but small document, which we can test as it is.

Comment: didn't work
but found the faulty line 
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{11pt}{0}\selectfont}

Answer (score 1):

With `\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{11pt}{0}\selectfont}` the space between the lines is non-existent, it should be bigger than the fontsize, for example `\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont}`

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\subsection{subsection}
\linespread{1.5} %regulate line spacing
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont} 
 erforschen desshalb die Häufigkeit und Intensitität von chronischer Müdigkeit und den möglichen Zusammenhang zu Schichtdiensten. Die Studie wird am Emergency Center des Clinical Center von Vojvodina in Novi Sad, Serbien im Zeitraum von Dezember 2012 bis Februar 2013 durchgeführt. Als Sample werden 120 zufällig gewählte Pflegekräfte der Krankenanstalt ausgewählt. 50\% der Gruppe (60 Personen) befinden sich in der Gruppe der im Schichtdienst arbeitenden. Die restlichen 50\% haben übliche 8 Stunden Tagesarbeitszeiten. Jede Testperson muss zwei Fragebögen ausfüllen. Einen um demographische Iformationen (Alter, Geschlecht, Jahre im Dienst, soziales Leben, ...) zu erfragen. Der zweite besteht aus einem standardisiertem Fragebogen um den Teilnehmern einen Wert entsprechend dem Piper Fatigue Scale (PFS) zu geben. Je höher dieser Wert, umso höher die chronische Müdigkeit. Ausgewertet werden die Ergebnisse Computerunterstützt.

Aufgrund der dempgraphischen Daten kann man an der Studie erkennen, das tendenziell jüngere Pflegekräfte im Schichtdienst arbeiten und ältere Pflegekräfte zum 8 Stunden Tag tendieren. Drüber hinaus sind die Antworten im FPS-Fragebogen in allen 22 Fragen, von Schichtarbeitenden Pflegekräften, signifikant höher (schlechter) bewertet. So wurde die subjektiv wahrgenommene Müdigkeit der letzten 7 Tage bei nichtschichtarbeitenden im Durchschnitt zwischen 1 und 6 bewertet. Die Schichtarbeitenden Kollegen und Kolleginnen hingegen bewerteten dies mit 6-10. Ebenso stellt sich heraus, dass verheiratete und Eltern tedenziell eher 8 Stunden Regeldienste bevorzugen. 

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{ | p{4cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | }
        \hline
           & 8-9h & 10-11h & 12-13h & >13h \\
         \hline
          Prozent von ALLEN Teilnehmern: & 26\% & 4\% & 65\% &   5\%  \\
         \hline
          Zufrieden mit dem Dienstplan & 85\% & 82\% & 88\% & 84\% \\
          Flexiebe Dienstpläne sind möglich: & 67\% & 65\% & 73\% & 66\% \\
          Burnout Risiko: & 20\% & 31\% & 44\% & 56\% \\
          Unzufirieden mit dem Job:  & 24\% & 35\% & 25\% & 43\% \\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{\ref{table:3} Anteil in \% nach Schichtgruppe ...}
    \label{table:3}
\end{table}
 erforschen desshalb die Häufigkeit und Intensitität von chronischer Müdigkeit und den möglichen Zusammenhang zu Schichtdiensten. Die Studie wird am Emergency Center des Clinical Center von Vojvodina in Novi Sad, Serbien im Zeitraum von Dezember 2012 bis Februar 2013 durchgeführt. Als Sample werden 120 zufällig gewählte Pflegekräfte der Krankenanstalt ausgewählt. 50\% der Gruppe (60 Personen) befinden sich in der Gruppe der im Schichtdienst arbeitenden. Die restlichen 50\% haben übliche 8 Stunden Tagesarbeitszeiten. Jede Testperson muss zwei Fragebögen ausfüllen. Einen um demographische Iformationen (Alter, Geschlecht, Jahre im Dienst, soziales Leben, ...) zu erfragen. Der zweite besteht aus einem standardisiertem Fragebogen um den Teilnehmern einen Wert entsprechend dem Piper Fatigue Scale (PFS) zu geben. Je höher dieser Wert, umso höher die chronische Müdigkeit. Ausgewertet werden die Ergebnisse Computerunterstützt.

Aufgrund der dempgraphischen Daten kann man an der Studie erkennen, das tendenziell jüngere Pflegekräfte im Schichtdienst arbeiten und ältere Pflegekräfte zum 8 Stunden Tag tendieren. Drüber hinaus sind die Antworten im FPS-Fragebogen in allen 22 Fragen, von Schichtarbeitenden Pflegekräften, signifikant höher (schlechter) bewertet. So wurde die subjektiv wahrgenommene Müdigkeit der letzten 7 Tage bei nichtschichtarbeitenden im Durchschnitt zwischen 1 und 6 bewertet. Die Schichtarbeitenden Kollegen und Kolleginnen hingegen bewerteten dies mit 6-10. Ebenso stellt sich heraus, dass verheiratete und Eltern tedenziell eher 8 Stunden Regeldienste bevorzugen. 
\end{document}
```

[image]